# Icon for menu selection/android

Tags: android, layout

I am in the process of creating a LinearLayout and within this layout...there will be a selection menu. I would like to know how it is possible to include an icon next to the text. This is the following code I have:

```
 <ImageView
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="175dp"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
<TextView
    android:text="Check Account"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_gravity="right"/>
</ImageView>
```

it is not working the way I want it to.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I donT know what you mean by "Selection menu"  but if you want this text + image to be an option that can be clicked, you might wanna use a normal [button](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html).

You can add a text and a drawable to on top/bottom/right/left of this text, together forming a single button.

```
<Button
     android:id="@+id/groups_button_bg"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:text="MenuOption1"
     android:drawableTop="@drawable/[image]" />
```

Comment: yay! got accepted :) .. but btw just in case u wanna create an "options/settings/preferences menu". Take a look at  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html